# Wordpress шорткоды (shortcode)

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Изучаю WP. 
Есть shortcode

```
add_shortcode( 'form', 'func_form' );

function func_form() {
    return "
    <form action=''>
        <label>Имя</label>
        <input type='text' name='name'>
        <label>Телефон</label>
        <input type='text' name='phone'>
        <input type='submit' name='btn'>
    </form>
";
}
```

Этот код я разместил в файле functions.php
Так же у меня есть обработчик. 
Это правильно, что я размещаю данные функций в файле functions.php или это можно отдельными файлами сделать?
Я пробую писать собственный плагин. Хотел что бы при активаций плагина shortcode стал активным. Как я могу это реализовать?

Comment: Я надеюсь это не реальный шорткод, а только его образец :)

Comment: Обычно код через include подключал(вёрстку и обработчик) У вас есть пример "правильного" шорткода?

Comment: Обычно вначале читают документацию. Там все примеры правильных шорткодов. А что касается форм.. тут вообще лучше использовать готовые плагины.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - разместите этот код в главном файле плагина. При активации плагина шорткод начнёт работать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать новый файл назвать его допустим shortcodes.php(наверное даже так правильней сделать) и все шорткоды помещать туда, и этот файл подключить в functions.php